# Mongo aggregation of list

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection like this:

```
{id:1, name: "fluffy", 
  toys: [{id: "mouse", colors: ['red', 'green']}, 
         {id: "yarn", colors: ['blue', 'green']]
},

{id:2, name: "rex", 
  toys: [{id: "bone", colors: ['gray']}]
}
```

I want to see results like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, name:"fluffy", toyColors:["red", "green", "blue"]},
  {id: 2, name:"rex", toyColors:["gray"]} 
]
```

I tried something like this, but I got 'lists of lists', instead of one big list for toy colors. Also, I did not know how to select the pet name with a query like this.

```
db.pets.aggregate({$group:{_id: "$id", toyColors: {$addToSet: "$toys.colors"}}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

```js
  db.pets.aggregate([
        // Unwind the array
        {$unwind: "$toys"},
        // Unwind the inner array
        {$unwind: "$toys.colors"},
        {$group:{_id: 
            { _id: "$id", name: "$name"},
            toyColors: {$addToSet: "$toys.colors"}}
        },
        {$project: { 
            _id: 0,
            _id: "$_id._id",
            name: "$_id.name",
            toyColors: 1
        }}
  ])
```

Also add the name in the grouping, and $project to get a nicer result.

Comment: This almost worked..its missing a comma after $_id.name and a closing curley brace at the end.

Comment: @Kyle It was just typed, not run. Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

You should use double `$unwind`:

```
db.pets.aggregate(
    { $unwind: "$toys" },
    { $unwind: "$toys.colors" },
    { $group: 
        {
            _id: "$_id",
            toyColors: {$addToSet: "$toys.colors"}      
        } 
    }
)
```

Comment: Oh. Another answer. You missed the name he asked for.

Comment: Yes, I've not noticed it. I think, that it is no sense to update answer :)

Comment: Sorry about that. In all fairness I made coffee while I was typing.